# How to generate verilog code like "reg[n-1:0] = 90" with chisel3?

Tags: chisel

I use chisel for FPGA development, for Vivado "reg[n-1:0] = 90" is effective.Many module have no reset input, so I can't use RegInit.
I saw a same question in [google chisel-users forum](https://groups.google.com/g/chisel-users/c/ipNOX7Ab1bY/m/piD334lrCwAJ),but no reply.

Answer (score 1):

Reset is implicit in Chisel `Module`, all `Reg` will have a reset. Then initial value will be set at reset following code

```scala
val myreg = RegInit(90.U((n-1).W))
```

But, for FPGA without reset input, we can generate it with a BlackBox with Verilog "inline" like [this module](https://github.com/Martoni/fpgamacro/blob/master/src/main/scala/fpgamacro/generic/resetgen.scala) :

```scala
class ResetGen extends BlackBox with HasBlackBoxInline {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val clk = Input(Clock())
    val rst = Output(Bool())
  })

  setInline("ResetGen.v",
    s"""
    |module ResetGen(
    |    input clk,
    |    output rst
    |);
    |
    |reg reset_reg = 0;
    |reg [7:0] reset_dly_cnt = 0;
    |always@(posedge clk) begin
    |  if(reset_dly_cnt < 8'hff)
    |      reset_dly_cnt <= reset_dly_cnt + 1'b1;
    |  else
    |      reset_reg <= 1;
    |end
    |
    |assign rst = !reset_reg;
    |endmodule
    """.stripMargin)
}
```

Then add the connexion in your Top :

```scala
class TopMyModule extends RawModule {
  val gclk = IO(Input(Clock()))
//...
  /* Generate the reset pulse */
  val rst = Wire(Bool())
  val rstgen = Module(new ResetGen())
  rstgen.io.clk := gclk
  rst := rstgen.io.rst

  /* Wrap all in gclk, rst domain */
  withClockAndReset(gclk, rst) {
      val myreg = RegInit(90.U((n-1).W))
//..
```

`myreg` will be initialized to 90 when `rst` signal is at 1.

Comment: I mean initial reg when it declare in verilog. Not subword assignment.

Comment: Thanks , I find a answer with a friend form gitter.  Essentially you need to:

`extend Module with RequireAsyncReset`
annotate the reset:
`annotate(new ChiselAnnotation {
 override def toFirrtl = PresetAnnotation(reset.toTarget)
})`
after that all of your `RegInit(...)` register will be initialized the way you want them to

Comment: Ok, can you explain in detailed answer to your question ?

Comment: Link to Gitter thread (https://gitter.im/freechipsproject/chisel3?at=612ef0168065e87a8ebb7dc4) but it would still be helpful if you could turn this into a full answer below.